# SQL compare two tables with common id

Tags: sql, compare

Given the following tables stored in SQL database

Table person

```
id   username   phone   
1    james      555-666-777
2    gabriel    666-555-777
3    Lucas      222-888-999
4    Marta      555-444-777
```

Table room_booking

```
id   person_id    room     time
1    2            A2       13:00
2    4            B5       09:00
3    1            C1       20:00
```

By only getting the `room_booking id number 2`
I would like the output to be:

Output table

```
id   username   phone 
4    Marta      555-444-777
```

I know `INNER JOIN` can do the job but I got fields from the table `room_booking` included with `SELECT *`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have said, the answer is to not include the unwanted columns.  Since you want all of the columns from one table, and none of the columns from the other table, the solution is to use person.*

```
Select distinct p.*
from person p
   Inner join room_booking r
      On r.person_id = p.id
```

I include the distinct because given your structure, you're likely to have more than one booking per person eventually.

Alternate syntax for achieving the same goal...

```
/*using sub select*/
Select * from person where id in (select person_id from room_booking);

 /*using cte, distinct and inner join*/
 ; pids as(select distinct person_id from room_booking)
 Select person.*
 from pids 
   Inner join person on person_id = id;

 /*using cte and subquery with explicit column list */
; pids as(select person_id from room_booking)
Select id, username, phone
from person 
Where id in (select person_id from pids)
```

Comment: Thanks for your elaborated answer! I finally changed the structure and I used sub select in my query. thanks for the distinct hint which I did not know.

Answer (score 2):

```
select
    p.id,
    p.username,
    p.phone
from Person p
inner join room_booking rb
on p.id = rb.person_id
where rb.id = 2
```

Alternatively you could select `p.*` but you shouldn't do that in prod code.

Comment: +1 for the select star comment.  Nothing breaks code quicker than a select star where the source table structure changes. :)

Comment: Ok thank you both for the input regarding the p.* I'll keep in mind that while the database keeps growing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You only get all fields included if you use the asterisk in the query. Try selecting only the fields you want to get:

```
SELECT person.id, username, phone 
FROM person JOIN room_booking ON person.id = room_booking.person_id 
WHERE room_booking.id = 2
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! good input with the Where in the end. I used person.* and I changed the structure as suggested by jmoreno.

Answer (score 1):

> I know INNER JOIN can do the job but I got fields from the table
>   room_booking included.

Don't select them and you won't get them:

```
select p.id   ,p.username   ,p.phone   from Person p 
inner join room_booking rb
on rb.person_id=p.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Both Return The Same Result

```
======================1
SELECT C.CountryName,C.ZipCode,P.Population
FROM tbl_Country C, tbl_Population P
WHERE C.ID= P.ID
======================2
SELECT C.CountryName,C.ZipCode,P.Population
FROM tbl_Country C inner join tbl_Population P
on C.ID= P.ID
```